# Spring Boot Cloud: JPA Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Generic Service

```
@Transactional
  public DTO forceSave(DTO DTO) {
      Model model = mapper.toModel(DTO);
      logger.info("DTO: {}" , model.toString());
      return mapper.toDTO(repository.save(model));
  }

  @Transactional
  public void delete(Set<ID> ids) {
    boolean anyNotFound = ids.stream().anyMatch((id) -> !repository.existsById(id));
    if (anyNotFound) {
      throw new NotFoundException("ID not found");
    }
    repository.softDeleteByIds(ids);
  }
```

Mapper

```
  @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
  public interface DrzavaMapper extends BaseMapper<Drzava, DrzavaDTO, Long>
```

Model

```
  public class Drzava extends BaseEntity<Long> {

  @Column(nullable = false)
    private String ime;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "drzava")
    private Set<Grad> gradovi;
  }
```

DTO

```
public class DrzavaDTO extends BaseDTO<Long> {
  @NotBlank(message = "Ime je obavezno")
  private String ime;
}
```

I use lombok but I omitted annotations just to make it easier to read. No @DaTa of course I know that causes recursion.
I tried @JsonIgnore @JsonBackReference an such to no avail.

```
@RestController
 @RequestMapping("/drzave")
  public class DrzavaController extends BaseController<Drzava, DrzavaDTO, Long> {
    private final DrzavaService service;

    public DrzavaController(DrzavaService service) {
        super(service);
        this.service = service;
    }
  }
```

http://localhost:8080/api/fakultet-service/drzave Post request

```
public DTO forceSave(DTO DTO) {
   Model model = mapper.toModel(DTO);
   logger.info("DTO: {}", model.toString());
   return mapper.toDTO(repository.save(model)); << error happens here, repository.Save
}
```

```
Error: 2023-06-30T11:07:46.690+02:00 WARN 20984 --- [nio-8082-exec-7] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError]
```

It "Resolves" error without a stack trace which is ridiculous, how to solve if I don't have information what went wrong, no stack trace nothing. Tried debugging with steps, it takes too long.
Tried everything changed to List from sets, every jackson json annotation possible. Nothing works. DTO is properly set, no recursion just one String field.

Latest Spring Boot and Cloud 3.1.1, java 17, mysql connector java latest version 8.0.33.

I also filled a bug report with JPA Spring. I turned on Hibernate SQL log and it doesn't even get there. Just says StackoverflowError and quits. It's driving me crazy.

[Error that I get, no stack trace, maybe somebody had the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKuMX.png)

Comment: Hello, toString() method is a suspect. Use ToString.exclude annotation the same way as JsonIgnore.

Comment: I had to use toString to display DTO content in logger. Only on this Entity others don't have toString annotation. Problem occurs on all Entities, all fail with POST request, others requests work fine.